# Subtract PHP variable from DB

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord, subtraction

I'm using codeigniter and trying to subtract one of my input values from the database with no luck. My current model is:

```
    $newstock = $this->input->post('f2');
            $itemname = $this->input->post('f1');
            $this->db->where('ItemName', $itemname); 
            $this->db->set('Stock', 'Stock-'.[$newstock], FALSE);
```

I get this Error:

```
Severity: Notice

Message: Array to string conversion

Filename: models/inventory.php
```

Comment: remove the bracket in $newstock

Comment: @Denmark I get this error when doing that: http://d.pr/i/EXZS

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution:

```
   $ItemName = $this->input->post('f2');
    $query = $this->db->select('Stock')->from('inventory')->get();
    foreach ($query->result() as $row)
        {
             $row->Stock;

        }
        $oldstock = $row->Stock;
        $numtosub = $this->input->post('f2');
        $numtosub;
        $newstock = $oldstock - $numtosub;
         $newstock;

    $data = array('Itemname' => $this->input->post('f1'),
                      'Stock' => $newstock,
                    );
    $data2 = array('Itemname' => $this->input->post('f1'),
                      'QuantitySold' => $this->input->post('f2'),
                      'Date' => standard_date()
                    );
            $this->db->insert('transactions', $data2);
            $itemname = $this->input->post('f1');
            $this->db->where('ItemName', $itemname); 
            $this->db->update('inventory', $data);
```

Thanks for your guys' help.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$this->db->set('Stock', 'Stock-'.$newstock, FALSE);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this code i make im not sure this will work but i think i give you an idea

```
function update(){
    $newstock = "Stock-".$this->input->post('f2');
    $itemname = $this->input->post('f1');

    $data = array("stock" => $newstock);
    $this->db->where('ItemName',$itemname);
    $this->db->update('inventory', $data);
}
```

Comment: I keep running into this: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Stock` = 'Stock-'' at line 1

UPDATE `stock` SET ` = '' WHERE `Stock` = 'Stock-'

Comment: what code did you use? and can you give me the exactly SQL query that you want to do

Comment: I want to run: UPDATE inventory SET stock = stock - $this->input->post('f2') WHERE ItemName = $this->input->post('f1')